# How do I sort two parameters The largest number should be displayed first, and then from the smallest to the largest

Tags: python

```
def funcSort(a = int(input()), b =  int(input()), c =  int(input()))
if a>b and a>c:
    print(a)
    print(sorted(b,c,sep="\n"))
elif b>c and b>a:
    print(b)
    print(sorted(a,c,sep="\n"))
elif c>a and c>b:
    print(a)
    print(sorted(b,a,sep="\n"))
```

Comment: Why not just `print(sorted([a, b, c]))`?

Comment: Use `sorted([variables])`.

Answer (score 1):

if you sort them into a list, you can then take the last number from the list using [-1] (this will be the largest), followed by all the other numbers using [0: -1] (this excludes the last number)

```
x = sorted([a, b, c])
print([x[-1], *x[0:-1]])
```